# Label at (1) is not in the same block as the goto statement at(2)

Tags: fortran, label, goto

I am a beginner in Fortran and I try to run something by using Fortran. Here is the error message shown in my programming:

> Label at （1） is not in the same block as the goto statement at (2).

Place (1) is the line of "66 CALL PRINT " and place (2) is the line of "GO TO 66". Could you please help me solve this problem? or could you recommand some materials about learning fortran to me? many thanks.

This is the part of my code:

```
      WRITE(6,600) ITR                                                  
  600 FORMAT(' RATIONAL EXPECTATIONS VARIABLES CONVERGED IN ',I4,       
     1' ITERATIONS')                                                    

   66 CALL PRINT    

   ......                                                   

   65 IF(ITR.LT.MAXITR) GOTO 62                                         

      WRITE(6,601) MAXITR                                               

  601 FORMAT(' RATIONAL EXPECTATIONS VARIABLES FAILED TO CONVERGE IN ', 

     1I4,' ITERATIONS')                                                 

      GO TO 66
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa3QY.png)

Comment: Firstly don't use goto - I can't remember when I last needed it in Fortran and it just leads to confusing and confused code. Secondly if somebody is teaching you as a beginner to use goto find a new teacher. Thirdly with what is here we can not answer your question - please show us at least the whole subprogram

Comment: Please add the error message as text not as an image.

Comment: @albert, please [don't edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350212/3157076) images to be visible when the images are of text.

Comment: @francescalus is this an official rule on stackoverflow or is it a preference / based on the given link so that OP has to include the image? (I hate the images as well).

Comment: @albert, it's a preference popular on meta rather than being "official" - but we've had mods in particular preferring it.  Probably as much as a "rule" as we can get.  (Not of course, that you won't be able to find popular posts saying the complete opposite...)  Thanks for roll-back.

Comment: @francescalus actually for code I 100% agree to have the code as text, for error messages I'm actually a bit in doubt as in some cases the the image shows exactly what is on the screen, and when the user uses cut and paste and is not familiar with the editing options some spacing might get lost (and with Fortran column 6  etc...).

Comment: @albert, I agree that there are subtleties and judgement can be applied in individual cases (and if the compiler's response to your code is for the computer to run away to elope with your younger sibling it may be hard to put the video adequately into text).

Comment: Most compilers try to make this work by dropping optimizations.  These are violations of Fortran standard, so you have no guarantee. In my old semi-automatic restructuring tools I expanded if else blocks to goto and applied the analysis to make new if else blocks and do enddo from scratch. It's important to have test cases to help determine whether attempted cleanup breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning, not an error. However it warns you that it's dangerous to jump into a different block of code. For example, what happens if you jump into a statement inside of a loop or another if block?